# Using apache reverse proxy for Domino inotes 8.5

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, ibm-domino

I have setup access for the users to their mailfiles on Domino 8.5.1 using Inotes. The reverse proxy in use is Apache. It works fine. This is the current configuration i am using. Virtual host is commented out.

The user types e.f.g.h and is being pointed to a.b.c.d and this works correctly without using virtual host. How would i implement this using Virtual Host

```
#<VirtualHost> 

ServerName ???

ProxyRequests off

ProxyPass / http://a.b.c.d/
ProxyPassReverse / http://a.b.c.d/
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Location />

ProxyHTMLEnable On 
ProxyHTMLURLMap / /
RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding

</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need the change is ..

```
`<VirtualHost server.site.com:80>`
```